# Paypal Payflow Sandbox ACH Error

Tags: php, paypal

I am running PayPals Payflow service in sandbox mode (or atleast trying to). When I make a call I only get the following:

```
RESULT=25
RESPMSG=Not signed up for this tender type
```

I am not passing credit card data, I am passing ACH data with bank routing information.

According to [PayPal](http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/result_values_for_transaction_declines_or_errors.htm), it says:

> Invalid Host Mapping. You are trying to process a tender type such as
>   Discover Card,  but you are not set up with your merchant bank to
>   accept this card type.

Does anyone know how I can **enable a sandbox in PayPal Payflow** to enable **ACH testing**? This account will never be used for anything except a sandbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to contact PayPal to add the ACH feature on my sandbox account.

Comment: I too get this done by requesting from the PayPal technical support. They responded me within a single day.